# Docker build mfp image with error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a DockerFile.

What I want to do is run a MobileFirst Image so that I can run inside it File.adapter files. So first I want to raise the application server with a dockerfile, unfornutally I got this output:

```
$ docker build -f ./doc .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/23 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 971bb384a50a
Step 2/23 : MAINTAINER Gabriel Mancini <gmancini@br.ibm.com> (@new_biel)
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2669f78208fd
Step 3/23 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https build-
ssential git-core wget unzip supervisor
 ---> Running in c846bc39a7a3
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

....

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/mult
verse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones use
 instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-http
 build-essential git-core wget unzip supervisor' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Gabriel Mancini <gmancini@br.ibm.com> (@new_biel)

# Install basics
RUN apt-get update && \ 
apt-get install -y \ 
apt-transport-https \ 
build-essential \ 
git-core \ 
wget \ 
unzip \ 
supervisor

# Install Java.
# add webupd8 repository
RUN \
    echo "===> add webupd8 repository..."  && \
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list  && \
    echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list  && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886  && \
    apt-get update  && \
    \
    \
    echo "===> install Java"  && \
    echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections  && \
    echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections  && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  apt-get install -y --force-yes oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default \
    maven && \
    \
    echo "===> clean up..."  && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer  && \
    apt-get clean  && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

# Install NodeJS
ENV NODE_VERSION 0.10.29
RUN \
  wget -q  -O - "http://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
  | tar xzf - --strip-components=1 --exclude="README.md" --exclude="LICENSE" \
  --exclude="ChangeLog" -C "/usr/local"

# Install node-gyp
RUN npm install -g node-gyp

# Install nodevisor
RUN git clone https://github.com/TAKEALOT/nodervisor.git /opt/nodervisor \
    && cd /opt/nodervisor \
    && npm install

# Install Mobile First Platform
ENV MFP_VERSION 7.0.0
RUN MFP_URL="https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_$MFP_VERSION.zip" \
    && wget -q $MFP_URL -U UA-IBM-WebSphere-Liberty-Docker -O "/tmp/mobilefirst_cli_installer_$MFP_VERSION.zip" \
    && unzip -q "/tmp/mobilefirst_cli_installer_$MFP_VERSION.zip" -d /tmp/mfp \
    && unzip -q "/tmp/mfp/mobilefirst-cli-installer-$MFP_VERSION/resources/mobilefirst-cli-$MFP_VERSION-install.zip" -d /opt/ibm \
    && rm -rf /tmp/mfp* \
    && cd /opt/ibm/mobilefirst-cli \
    && npm install
ENV PATH /opt/ibm/mobilefirst-cli:$PATH
ENV PATH node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV PATH node_modules/bin:$PATH

# Configure mfp
COPY mfp /opt/ibm/mobilefirst-cli/mfp
RUN chmod 755 /opt/ibm/mobilefirst-cli/mfp

# Configure supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
RUN chmod 755 /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Configure WebSphere Liberty
RUN mfp create-server

EXPOSE 10080 3000
#WORKDIR /workspace
VOLUME /workspace

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
#CMD ["mfp", "-d", "start"]
```

Can you guide me what could be going wrong?
Im running it in windows 7 in dockerToolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.4 is rather old now, consider a newer one, if possible. I don't know if updates for it are being published now.

If you have to use it, you might not be able to pull updates for it anymore. If there are no updates, the latest versions of all packages (at the time the last updates were published) should be available on archive.ubunut.com. There may be a handy replacement for `/etc/apt/sources.list` somewhere that is configured to use the archive and works for Ubuntu 14.

Comment: I got the same error using ubuntu:latest Step 3/23 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https build-e
ssential git-core wget unzip supervisor  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
 build-essential git-core wget unzip supervisor' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: There may be something wrong with accessing the Ubuntu servers in general from your location. You may want to check if there's any firewall or proxy that blocks this access.

Comment: Ill check at home how the built goes and update here the output , thanks

Comment: Which command failed and how? Note 'COPY mfp ...' attempts to copy a file named 'mfp' from the directory on your host (where you run 'docker build'). Do you have such a file? Another thing you might want to correct: adding relative directories (such as 'node_modules/bin') to the path will not work well - correct operation would depend on what the current directory is.